# Setting up disabled state for custom UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I've created the following custom UIButton:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class WhiteGhostYouButton: UIButton {

    required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        self.titleLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white
        self.borderWidth = 2
        self.borderColor = UIColor.white
        self.cornerRadius = 23
    }
}
```

This works great!

Now I also want to implement a custom Disabled state for this button.

How do I go about this?

This doesn't seem to work:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class GhostYouButton: UIButton {
    required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        if (self.isEnabled == false) {
            self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            self.titleLabel?.textColor = Constant.disabledGrayColor
            self.tintColor = Constant.disabledGrayColor
            self.borderColor = Constant.disabledGrayColor
            self.borderWidth = 2
            self.cornerRadius = 20
        } else {
            self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            self.titleLabel?.textColor = Constant.mainGreenColor
            self.tintColor = Constant.mainGreenColor
            self.borderColor = Constant.mainGreenColor
            self.borderWidth = 2
            self.cornerRadius = 20
        }
    }
}
```

The viewDidLoad that disables my button:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.nextButton.isEnabled = false
}
```

Comment: just add `self.isEnabled = false`

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I've updated my question

Comment: what the output you expect, in which state you want to disable this

Comment: I want the button to be gray when disabled. green when enabled. I disable the button in the viewDidLoad function.

Comment: ok show that viewdidload code also

Comment: ok when you enabled the button is true

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can try to implenment the `didSet` of `isEnable`:

```
override var isEnabled: Bool {
        didSet {
            if (self.isEnabled == false) {
               self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
               self.titleLabel?.textColor = Constant.disabledGrayColor
               self.tintColor = Constant.disabledGrayColor
               self.borderColor = Constant.disabledGrayColor
               self.borderWidth = 2
               self.cornerRadius = 20
           } else {
               self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
               self.titleLabel?.textColor = Constant.mainGreenColor
               self.tintColor = Constant.mainGreenColor
               self.borderColor = Constant.mainGreenColor
               self.borderWidth = 2
               self.cornerRadius = 20
           }
    }
```

hope this can help you :)

Answer (score 0):

For customizing the WhiteGhostYouButton as per the states like disabled state. You need to add drawRect method inside the custom class as per below code snippet.

```
class WhiteGhostYouButton: UIButton {

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    super.draw(rect)
    if self.isEnabled = false {
   //Customize UI here        
      } esle {
      }
   }
}
```

On any event like button press, re rendering of view can be forced as per below code snippet

```
 @IBAction func button_Pressed(sender: AnyObject) {
         sender.setNeedsDisplay()
    }
```